# Retrieving data from NSUserDefaults - works in one view but fails in another

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm saving the logged in Facebook username to the NSUserDefaults preferences using the code below (from the AppDelegate file). The code retrieves the username and outputs it to the console just fine. When I try to do the same thing in another view controller the NSLog output returns (null).

What am I missing? Thanks for any help.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary* hash = result;
        NSString *username = (NSString*)[hash valueForKey:@"name"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:username forKey:@"Username"];
        NSLog(@"%@", username);
        NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *user = [standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"Username"];
        NSLog(@"username from user defs %@",user);
    }
};
```

Here's the code from the other view controller that isn't working:

```
NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *user = [standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"Username"];
NSLog(@"username from user defs %@",user);
userNameLbl.text = user;
```

Here's the log output:

```
username from user defs app delegate my Facebook name
2012-03-30 13:29:20.564 project V2[63339:15803] (null)
2012-03-30 13:29:20.565 project V2[63339:15803] username from user defs app delegate (null)
2012-03-30 13:29:28.620 project V2[63339:15803] username from user defs (null)
```

Comment: I added #import "AppDelegate.h" to the view controller and all is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *user = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Username"];
NSLog(@"username from user defs %@",user);
userNameLbl.text = user;
```

Try this (I changed just one line)

```
NSString *user = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Username"];
```

**EDIT**
This is how i save things to NSUserDefaults;

```
NSString *theKeyIWantToSave;
NSUSerDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:theKeyIWantToSave forKey:@"SomeKey"];
```

And whenever/whereever i want to retrieve it

```
NSString *key=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SomeKey"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:newStr forKey:@"Username"];
```

for setting and:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Username"];
```

for getting it. No imports, nothing!

Comment: I was over writing it by setting the NSString *user = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"Username"]; twice. doh!

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake is forgetting or not knowing to save your defaults.. 
Call:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

This will write your defaults to file allowing you to retrieve them next time.